# ElasticSearch Source Filtering does not Always Work with Multi Search JavaScript/Node API

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, source-filter

The source filtering feature of ElasticSearch 2.3 does not always work when used with multi search (msearch) in JavaScript/Node API. I tried different combinations like _sourceInclude, _source_include, _source: {include: 'specificField'}, and also ['specificField'] instead of 'specificField'.

Any clue?

`params.searches = [
    {
        _type: 'Doc',
        _source: 'specificField'
    },
    {query: {constant_score: {filter: {bool: {must: [
        {term: {id: params.id}},
        {term: {anotherField: false}}
    ]}}}}},
];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source should be specified along with the query and not with the `index` and `type`

*Example*:

```
params.searches = [
    {"index":"test", "_type":"Doc"},
    {
     "_source": [
         "specificField"
      ],
     "query": {
       "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
           "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "id": "params.id"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "anotherField": "false"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
]
```